# Field Section Taking Precedence Over Standard Page Layout?

Tags: lightning-apps, page-layout

I recently added a 'Field Section' to a Lightning App Page for the 'Account' object. Now, when I create a new record using the 'New' button on the Account List View, the fields on the standard Page Layout are not displaying, only the field that has been added to the Field Section.

[image]

My understanding is that the Field Section which contains the 'Important Notes' field is taking precedence over the fields on the Standard Page Layout. This would make sense to me, but I replicated this in another environment and it IS working- that is, all of the fields on the Standard Page Layout are displaying, and NOT the field from the Field Section.

Is there some sort of setting that controls which layout takes precedence over the other? I am a bit stuck on this.

Thanks!